# Dynamically count of similar kind of Data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic, foreach, dataset

I have one data table in VB page which contain bulk data.In that data table one column named as vType and values in that column is one of Pr defined values such as  'A','B','C','D' etc , which comes from one Datable.
Now I want count of each type at the end.
For ex : CountA = 20,CountB=25 and so on .

Till now I have compared Each value using If condition which is static

```
For each dr as dataRow in dsType.rows
If dr("vType") = 'A' Then
                    CountA += 1
ElseIf dr("vType") = 'B' Then
                    CountB +=1
Next dr
```

and this If condition will repeat depend upon no of types in that data table (at max 8 fix values) I want to do this in single if condition ( Dynamic if Possible) Can I Count these values and store the same into single varaible?  appreciate for you prompt reply.

Comment: You're attracting close votes because this question isn't very clear. Could you explain it a bit better please, particularly the last paragraph?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Linq-To-DataSet` and `Enumerable.GroupBy` + `Enumerable.Count` on each group:

```
Dim typeGroups = dsType.AsEnumerable().
    GroupBy(Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("vType")).
    Select(Function(g) New With{ .Type = g.Key, .Count = g.Count(), .TypeGroup = g })
```

Note that `New With` creates an anonymous type in VB.NET with custom properties. So like a class *on-the-fly* which you can use in the current method.

Now you can enumerate the query with `For Each`:

```
For Each typeGroup In typeGroups
    Console.WriteLine("Type:{0} Count:{1}", typeGroup.Type, typeGroup.Count)
Next
```

---

> I cannot use Linq, i need to use simple vb only

Then use a `Dictionary`:

```
Dim typeCounts = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
For Each row As DataRow In dsType.Rows
    Dim type = row.Field(Of String)("vType")
    If (typeCounts.ContainsKey(type)) Then
        typeCounts(type) += 1
    Else
        typeCounts.Add(type, 1)
    End If
Next
```

Now you have  a dictionary where the key is the type and the value is the count of the rows with this type.

Comment: This may solve using LINQ , but I do not want to use LINQ for the same.I need to use simple vb page only.

Comment: _"I do not want to use LINQ for the same"_ What does that mean?

Comment: @Mudassir: Edited my answer to provide a simple VB.NET solution which is also very efficient.

Comment: i.e I am not allowed to Use concept of LINQ for this solution...SO that I need to find simplest solution using VB only

Comment: @Mudassir: As i have already mentioned, i have edited my answer to provide a non-Linq solution.

Answer (score 0):

why not getting the pretend result from the db itself?
Like so:

```
select count(*), vType
from someTable
group by vType
```

Comment: Suggest this to everyone who asks about linq :-)

Comment: Yes indeed, a very strange SQL incantation. :-)

Comment: @CarlosB : Sometable's name is "dsAllType" Which contains distinct 8 values(at max 8 records).where as These 8 values comes multiple time in dsType dataset which has more rows,so can not use it directly

Comment: @Mudassir you are not providing enough information. what comes in a dataset is what you want to get there. What you need to give us is an actually description of the database. I'm still convinced this can be done directly in sql then returned to a VB dataset

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure about your question .. but this is what I've considered ..

You can make it as Sub ..

```
Sub AssignIncr(ByVal ds as DataSet,byval sFi as String,byval sCrit as String,ByRef Counter as Integer)
  For each dr as dataRow in ds.rows
    If dr(sFi) = sCrit Then Counter += 1
  Next dr
End Sub
```

So you may use it by ..

```
AssignIncr(dsType,"vType","A",CountA)
```